# Velocity templates in sub directories

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity, subdirectory

I have spring-mvc project configuration with velocity configured like:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="false" />
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView"/>
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true" /> 
</bean>
```

Strucrute od WEB-INF is:

/WEB-INF/velocity/ 
/WEB-INF/velocity/login.vm 
/WEB-INF/velocity/register.vm 
/WEB-INF/velocity/account/forget.vm

I can open login page and register page with no problem using:

example.com/login.vm 
example.com/register.vm

but i cannot access 
example.com/account/forget.vm

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your controller also.

Comment: Thanks! Santosh Joshi That was it.... I forget to put controller and i expect to find the template without controller mapping.